# Como puedo sacarle la suma a esta matrix

Tags: python, algoritmos, matrices

Ayuda por favor como creo  un algoritmo que calcule la suma del triángulo inferior más el triángulo superior de una matriz cuadrada de n X n, dejando el resultado en el triángulo inferior de otra matriz cuadrada de dimensión n X n.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces la matriz resuelta tendria que quedar asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que llevo hasta el momento es este :

```
import random


def listaAleatorios(n): 
    lista = [0]  * n

    for i in range(n):
        lista[i] = random.randrange(1,10)

    return lista

nm = int(input("coloque el numero del lado del cubo : >>"))
ml = []#la matrix de las listas aleatorias

for k in range(nm): #para generar las listas aleatorias
    v = listaAleatorios(nm)
    ml.append(v)


def print_r(matriz):   #para mostrar la matrix ordenada
    for fila in matriz:
        print(fila)


print("Original")
print_r(ml)


for i in range(0,len(ml)):
    a = len(ml)
    j = 1
    print("alto",ml[i][i+1::j]) # posiciones del triangulo superior
    j +=1
    print("bajo",ml[i][0:i])# posiciones del triangulo inferior  
    #ml[i][i:a] = "0"*(a-i) este reemplaza los valores
```

Comment: Ahora si podemos empezar a hablar sobre algo concreto :). He editado la pregunta formateando el código correctamente ya que es tu primera vez por aquí. Para sucesivos post recuerda formatear correctamente el código, para ello lo copias, lo seleccionas todo y pulsas el botón `{}` del editor o Ctrl + k. Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla gracias por la ayuda, la verdad es que si es la primera vez que hago una pregunta

Comment: No te preocupes, ya irás aprendiendo como funciona el sitio poco a poco. Te he dejado una respuesta con una forma de abordarlo a ver que te parece, cambio un poco tu enfoque pero la base es la misma que usas tu, slicing de listas y ciclos `for`. Saludos.

Comment: Me parece muy interesante el modo en el que lo solucionastes, la verdad no tenia la certeza de que podia hacerlo con (Zip).Gracias!

Comment: Juan pues si, `zip` biene muy bién para iterar sobre elementos de varios iterables a la vez. No dices que versión de Python usas, si usas Python 2.x es mejor usar [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) ya que no crea una lista sino que genera un iterador como hace `zip` en Python 3. Sería incluso más fácil hacer esto usando NumPy pero eso ya es una librería externa. Saludos.

Comment: en estos momentos utilizo python 3.x, siendo asi me pondre a estudiar mas a fondo la libreria Numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema por lo que veo es obtener el triángulo inferior. No obstante yo tomaria un enfoque algo distinto:

- Obtenemos el triangulo inferior como tal. Para ello basta con un `for` que itere desde la fila 1 (no desde la 0 que ya pertenece a la diagonal) y hacer un slicing como haces tu para obtener el superior:

  ```
  t_inf = []
  for i in range(1, len(ml)):
      t_inf.append(ml[i][:i])
  ```
- Obtener el triángulo superior. No obstante, en realidad necesitamos el triangulo superior pero transpuesto, para sumarlo con el inferior. Para ello necesitamos tomar las columnas y no las filas como antes. Esto se puede hacer usando un `for` anidado:

  ```
  t_sup = []
  for i in range(1, len(ml)):
      aux = []
      for j in range(0, i):
          aux.append(ml[j][i])
      t_sup.append(aux)
  ```
- Ahora solo tenemos que sumar ambas listas. Para ello lo más simple es usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

  ```
  suma = []
  for fila1, fila2 in zip(t_sup, t_inf):
      aux = []
      for n1, n2 in zip(fila1, fila2):
          aux.append(n1+n2)
      suma.append(aux)
  ```

Todo junto aplicado sobre la matriz ejemplo que das sería algo así:

```
def print_r(matriz):   #para mostrar la matrix ordenada
    for fila in matriz:
        print(fila)

ml = [[5, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      [1, 6, 4, 5,  6],
      [2, 3, 9, 2,  3],
      [4, 5, 6, 4,  1],
      [7, 8, 9, 3, 10]]

t_sup = []
t_inf = []
suma = []

for i in range(1, len(ml)):
    aux = []
    for j in range(0, i):
        aux.append(ml[j][i])
    t_sup.append(aux)
    t_inf.append(ml[i][:i])

for fila1, fila2 in zip(t_sup, t_inf):
    aux = []
    for n1, n2 in zip(fila1, fila2):
        aux.append(n1+n2)
    suma.append(aux)



print("Original")
print_r(ml)
print()
print('Triangulo superior transpuesto:\n', t_sup)
print('Triangulo inferior:\n', t_inf)
print('Suma:\n', suma)
```

La salida es:

> ```
> Original
> [5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
> [1, 6, 4, 5, 6]
> [2, 3, 9, 2, 3]
> [4, 5, 6, 4, 1]
> [7, 8, 9, 3, 10]
>
> Triangulo superior transpuesto:
>  [[7], [8, 4], [9, 5, 2], [10, 6, 3, 1]]
> Triangulo inferior:
>  [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 3]]
> Suma:
>  [[8], [10, 7], [13, 10, 8], [17, 14, 12, 4]]
> ```

También puedes usar compresión de listas y generadores que son más eficientes:

```
def print_r(matriz):   #para mostrar la matrix ordenada
    for fila in matriz:
        print(fila)

ml = [[5, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      [1, 6, 4, 5,  6],
      [2, 3, 9, 2,  3],
      [4, 5, 6, 4,  1],
      [7, 8, 9, 3, 10]]

t_sup = ((ml[j][i] for j in range(0, i)) for i in range(1, len(ml)))
t_inf = (ml[i][:i] for i in range(1, len(ml)))
suma = [[a+b for a, b in zip(row1, row2)] for row1, row2 in zip(t_sup, t_inf)]

print("Original")
print_r(ml)
print()
print('Suma:\n', suma)
```

Solo te queda añadir los ceros que faltan a cada fila y lo tienes hecho.